# Orthogonality and Inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(|)$ is standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a linear operator s.t. $ T(x_1, x_2) = (-x_2, x_1)$. Then $(\alpha| T(\alpha)) = 0$ $\forall$ $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Here is no problem, but the followings.

1. Find all inner product $[|]$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ s.t. $[\alpha | T(\alpha)] = 0$ $\forall$ $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

I have tried a little.

Define $p_T(\alpha | \beta) = (T(\alpha) | T(\beta)) = a_2 b_2 + a_1 b_1$ where $\alpha = (a_1, a_2)$ and $\beta = (b_1, b_2)$.

Thus $p_T(\alpha | T(\alpha)) = (T(\alpha) | T(T(\alpha))) = 0$. So there should be some relationship between $[|]$ and $p_T(|)$. But I am not getting any more.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note $p_T(\alpha\mid\beta) = (\alpha\mid\beta)$ ($T$ is orthogonal). An inner product is given by $\langle x\mid y\rangle = x^t\cdot M\cdot y$, where $M$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. What does $\langle x\mid Ty\rangle = 0$ imply for the representing matrix $M$?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Thank you for your hints, actually I did not think to use the matrix representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner products on $\mathbb{R}^2$ are the same as symmetric positive-definite matrices

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a   &   b  \\
b   &   c
\end{pmatrix}  \ .
$$

That is, your inner product can be computed as

$$
[(x,y)\ \vert\ (z,t)] =
(x,y) 
\begin{pmatrix}
a   &   b  \\
b   &   c
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
z   \\
t
\end{pmatrix}  \ .
$$

So, if we say that it must be zero on $[v \ \vert T(v)]$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$, we are asking for the following polynomial to be identically zero:

$$
[(x,y)\ \vert\ (-y, x)] =
(x,y) 
\begin{pmatrix}
a   &   b  \\
b   &   c
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-y   \\
x
\end{pmatrix}
=
bx^2 - by^2 + (c-a)xy \ .
$$

Hence, we must have $b = 0$ and $c = a$. That is, the matrix of our inner product must be a multiple of the identity matrix, $aI$, for some $a\in \mathbb{R}, \ a > 0$ (this last condition, in order to be positive-definite).

Comment: Thank you, it is clear now.